# Javascript parseInt method returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sum two variables. Suppose count = 1 and get_item_amount = 3

```
count = parseInt(count) + get_item_amount
```

```
output : 13
```

When I am converting variable to integer it returns NaN. I don't know why I can't convert the value from string to int. jQuery are getting correctly value from input element when I debug with console.log without parseInt method.

```
$("[id^=item-]").each(function(){

 var get_item_amount = $(this).val();
 count = parseInt(count) + parseInt(get_item_amount)

 console.log(count)

});
```

```
output: NaN
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: look like `html` needed *!*

Comment: Try to log `count` and `get_item_amount` _before_ you do the calculation and see what their value is.

Comment: If either `count` or `get_item_amount` is empty (string) parseInt will return `NaN`.

Comment: What is `parseInt(count)` in `parseInt(count)`

Comment: I already knew the way to solve this problem. Because some element of $("[id^=item-]") are empty string and it will return NaN then i add condition statement to accept only value greater than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***It seems some of your input have the empty string.***

`parseInt("")` returns `NaN`, you can use [**`Number()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) Instead. Converting the empty string with [**`Number()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) will give you `0` and you will get the expected result through addition.

**Please Note:** You can still use `parseInt()` by filtering out the inputs with empty values using [Attribute Not Equal Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) like the following way:

```js
var count = 0;
$("[id^=item-][value!='']").each(function(){
 var get_item_amount = $(this).val();
 count = parseInt(count) + parseInt(get_item_amount);
 console.log(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-1" placeholder="จำนวน" value="11">

<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-2" placeholder="จำนวน" value="">

<input class="input item-input" type="text" id="item-3" placeholder="จำนวน" value="33">
```

Comment: Oh, i got it. I adding condition to check $(this).val(); greater than zero. because some element are empty string and it will return NaN, So it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Thank you.

```
$("[id^=item-]").each(function(){
 if($(this).val() > 0) {
  var get_item_amount = $(this).val();
  count = parseInt(count) + parseInt(get_item_amount)
 }
});
```

Comment: Do `typeof($(this).val())`. If it is a string then comparing it with 0 may not work